# ReactJS: Go to anchor link in HTML with react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am developing an app with patch notes where I have url's with the following structure defined with React Router:

```
<Route path='/updates/:id?' render={(params) => <Updates {...params} />}></Route>
```

I want to allow user to go to a specific part of the document if the url contains a hash part like this `/updates/1#index`. Here, the `#index` part of the url should send the user to the div with `id='index'` just like normal HTML.

I read about hashRouter with normal HTML for `{content}` but it didn't work as I expected or required:

```
<HashRouter>
  {content}
</HashRouter>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to scroll to the element with specified `id`?

Comment: @DacreDenny Yeah, I want to this works like normal HTML but with React router dom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [`Element#scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to mimic the default browser behavior of anchor link.

For instance, if `<Updates />` is the component that hosts your patch note content (where anchor links are defined), then you could run this function when `<Updates />` is [mounted](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) or [started](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to achieve this:

```
function scrollToHash() {

    /* Obtain hash from current location (and trim off leading #) */
    const id = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    if(id) {
        /* Find matching element by id */
        const anchor = document.getElementById(id);

        if(anchor) {
            /* Scroll to that element if present */
            anchor.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
}

/* Usage example */
function Updates() {

    React.useEffect(() => {
        scrollToHash();
    },[]);

    /* Render patch content that contains anchors */
    return <div> ... </div>
}
```